# EPPlus opening excel .xlsx file error

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx, epplus, vba

```
public void DailyOvertime(string fname)
  {
      var existingFile = new FileInfo(fname);

      using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
      {
          // Get the work book in the file
           ExcelWorkbook workBook = package.Workbook;
          if (workBook != null)
          {
              if (workBook.Worksheets.Count > 0)
              {
                  // Get the first worksheet
                  ExcelWorksheet currentWorksheet = workBook.Worksheets.First();

                  // read some data                    
                  var Monday = currentWorksheet.GetValue(11, 4);
                  var Tuesday = currentWorksheet.GetValue(13, 4);
                  var Wednesday = currentWorksheet.GetValue(15, 4);
                  var Thursday = currentWorksheet.GetValue(17, 4);
                  var Friday = currentWorksheet.GetValue(19, 4);
                  var Saturday = currentWorksheet.GetValue(21, 4);
                  var Sunday = currentWorksheet.GetValue(23, 4);

              }

          }
      }
  }
```

I am getting an error while running this code. Every time I get to the line `ExcelWorkbook workBook = package.Workbook;` the program will break and I cant figure out why. I'm trying to open an .xlsx file and everything seems to be working fine up to that point.

I did notice that this message was coming up in the Locals:

`Workbook   'package.Workbook' threw an exception of type 'System.UriFormatException'   OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook {System.UriFormatException}`

Any help would be appreciated Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked if any exception is being thrown in that line by using the debugger? Post the exception so that it would be helpful to narrowdown the issue.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan:Nothing was thrown, it just breaks to the application without any information being given

Comment: Do you have the XLSX file open in Excel? That always happens to me...

Comment: @ThomasW: I did accidentally do that a couple time, however regardless of it being open or not I still got the same issue

Answer (score 1):

From the exception message, it seems highly likely that your Excel file has URIs in an incorrect format, and some versions of EPPlus throw exceptions in opening workbooks with incorrect URIs.

Make sure you get the latest version of EPPlus from code plex, apparently the latest versions have patches that resolve this specific issue.

Check out [this](https://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/14823) and [this](https://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/14709). At the time of posting this answer, some comments in codeplex epplus branch say that this issue isn't fixed.

Alternatively, you could check-out some other libraries that could help in reading xls files. Check if [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) could suit your needs.

Comment: updating to latest version worked for resolving the issue for me. thanks!